# Отправить изображения на сервер

Tags: java, android

Пишу первое приложения и пытаюсь сделать отправку изображения на сервер но не могу найти нормального ресурса где бы мне все тщательно объяснялось. Если у вас есть ссылки на литературу, документации , тутариалы или уроки то я с удовольствием почитал бы. Заранее спасибо

Comment: покажите что конкретно не получается. Как отправляете и как принимаете.

Comment: @Виктор я навичек и я даже не имею понятие каким способом можно отправить изоброжения на сервер)

Comment: тогда на чем написан сервер? т.е. какие технологии использовали? чистые сервлеты, spring ...?

Comment: @Виктор Простой ПХП. принять фото на чистым пхп разве нельзя?

Comment: принять можно на чем угодно, главное чтобы принимающая сторона понимала, что ей отправили изображение и соответственно достала его из запроса.

Comment: @Виктор Ну вото. Что нибудь по советуете? может какую нибудь легкую библиотеку?

Comment: часто видел, что для http запросов использовали OkHttp. Я под андроид не пишу, поэтому использую Apache HttpClient

Comment: @Виктор Понятно